# Support for Dolby Digital?

Tags: audio, 4.4-kitkat

I have an embedded Android system and I connect it to my TV via HDMI.

Also my system has an Optical audio port.

I would like to know...

Does Android support Dolby digital (via MHL or HDMI or any other option)?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, Campiador! Please note that our site works best using exactly one question per post. I'd suggest you keep the first here, as further, development questions are off-topic at this place (see our [help/on-topic] for details). They are dealt with at our sister-site [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).

Comment: Thanks for updating. I just did a little Google search, and wrote an answer. Note that I didn't dig very deep, and have made no practical tests.

Answer (score 2):

Though I found no concrete specs saying all (or which) Android devices might (or might not) support it, there are strong indications that it's possible (and at least partly supported):

- Jabra [advertizes its app](http://www.jabra.com/headsets-and-speakerphones/all-products/apps/dolby-and-jabra-sound-app) for Dolby sound. No explicit mention of "Dolby *digital*, though.
- XDA has a thread titled [Beats audio with dolby digital advanced audio](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1848616); as you can see, this *explicitly* mentions "Dolby *digital"*. As this discusses an Android app, this pre-supposes the technical possibility.
- AndroidAyuda.com has a [Spanish article](http://androidayuda.com/2013/06/16/instala-beats-audio-sony-clearaudio-y-dolby-digital-en-tu-android/) on this topic, which also implicates the availability

There are about 5 million hits for a [google search on 'android "dolby digital"'](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+%22dolby+digital%22&ie=UTF-8&nfpr=1&safe=active&hl=en), which you might want to check some more from. The few I've picked didn't state any restrictions as to the device (though there are probably some, for what use does the support make if you have no appropriate output, such as HDMI). But it's clear that the Android *OS* is no hindrance to it.

**TL;DR:** Android itself can obviously deal with it, if the device supports it.

Answer (score 0):

android does not support dolby (digital) / DTS
dont compare beats with dolby / DTS
beats is just an equalizer software layer in between your mixer in android
it doesnt encode audio streams from applications, applications have to have build in support for that

for music dolby playback its useless, for video playback it is impossible
since android needs to have encoder support in the kernel itself
then the application for playback needs to support it

dolby digital is not giving licence to android platform, they are very picky
ipad and macs have encoder support and licence for it

for example cinexplayer for iOS has exellent support for dolby/dts
cinexplayer has also an android app, but no dolby/dts support duo android limitations

i'm android developer and tried all sorts of things by using code hacks in custom roms to get
some kind of dolby playback

if the music/video app doesnt support build in dolby/dts then obviously
you cannot encode the audio stream for dolby/dts so it doesnt matter
even if you have support in the kernel and beats audio and all that crap

Answer (score 0):

> Dolby® Digital Plus™ is built into many Android devices out in the market. This means
>   Android Applications and Games can have amazing immersive sound by
>   integrating the Dolby® Audio API for Android™

Support is there in many of the devices, but it is up to the developers of the games/applications to implement it:

[Dolby API for Android](http://developer.dolby.com/tools-tech.aspx#android)